# .htaccess rewrite subdomain as request parameter

Tags: php, wildcard, subdomain

Ho I Can rewrite this request types:

```
http://name1.domain1.com/        -> index.php?subdomain=name1
http://name2.domain2.org/        -> index.php?subdomain=name2
```

I need manage subdomain GET variable in php script ( index.php ).
I need of generic rule for all domain.

This is my .htaccess file, but it's not working.

```
RewriteEngine On

# Parse the subdomain as a variable we can access in PHP, and
# run the main index.php script
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}        !^www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}         ^([^\.]+)\.([^\.]+)\.([^\.]+)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1?subdomain=%1
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using PHP. You don't need to put it as query parameter since from PHP you can already see which is the URL the client's browser requested.

```
echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']
```

**output:**

```
bubbles.domain.com
```

You just need to parse it.

```
$host= (explode( '.', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']))[0];
$subdomain = $host[0];

if($subdomain == 'www' || $subdomain == 'www2') 
    $subdomain = $host[1];

echo $subdomain;
```

**output:**

```
bubbles
```

Comment: If isset "www" prefix:

$host = explode('.',$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']));

if(count($host) == 3) { // esiste il www
 $subdomain = $host[1];
} elseif($host == 2) { // non esiste www
$subdomain = $host[0];
}
Do you agree?